# How to sort a given list of strings in a custom order?

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
input_list = ["G1","G2","G5","G4","G3","R1","R2","R3","R5","R4"] 

output_list = ["R1","R2","R3","R4","R5""G1","G2","G3","G5","G4"]
```

Code I tried:

```
new_list = []
for i in sorted(input_list):
    new_list.append(i)
print (new_list[::-1])
```

Actual Output : `['R5', 'R4', 'R3', 'R2', 'R1', 'G5', 'G4', 'G3', 'G2', 'G1']`

Expected Output : `["R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "G1", "G2", "G3", "G5", "G4"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unsorted_list = ["G1","G2","G5","G4","G3","R1","R2","R3","R5","R4"]

sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: (-ord(x[0]), x[1]))

print(sorted_list)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to sort *descending* by the letter component followed by *ascending* by the number component.  One option uses list `sort()` with a lambda expression:

```py
input_list = ["G1","G2","G5","G4","G3","R1","R2","R3","R5","R4"]
input_list.sort(key=lambda x: (re.sub(r'\d+$', '', x), -int(re.sub(r'^[A-Z]+', '', x))), reverse=True)
print(input_list)
```

This prints:

```
['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
```

Comment: Stuff like this really makes me realize that much to learn I still have

Comment: @CamiloMartínez I wanted a shorter way of doing this, but this is the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm as much of a fan of regular expressions as the next guy, but assuming the elements of the input list are uniform (a single capital letter followed by a single digit), I believe something (arguably) simpler is possible.

```
unsorted_list = ["G1","G2","G5","G4","G3","R1","R2","R3","R5","R4"]

sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: (-ord(x[0]), x[1]))

print(sorted_list)
```

Output:

```
['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
```

Answer (score 0):

inp = ["R1","G2","R5","G1","R4","R2","R3","G4","G3","G5"]
#exp_opt = [R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,G1,G2,G3,G4,G5]

print(sorted(inp))

this is the simplest way to sort things apart from using regex